# Merge and sort associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

First array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [occ] => 14 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [occ] => 12 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 4 [occ] => 2 ) 
)
```

Second array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [company_name] => Google   [CEO] => Mike ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [company_name] => Apple    [CEO] => Jones) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [company_name] => Bmw      [CEO] => Steve) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 3 [company_name] => Hardsoft [CEO] => Lucy ) 
    [4] => Array ( [id] => 4 [company_name] => Lays     [CEO] => Morty) 
)
```

I Would like to merge these arrays to something like that:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [company_name] => Google   [CEO] => Mike   [occ] => 14) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [company_name] => Apple    [CEO] => Jones  [occ] => 12) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [company_name] => Bmw      [CEO] => Steve  [occ] => 0) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [company_name] => Hardsoft [CEO] => Lucy   [occ] => 2) 
    [4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [company_name] => Lays     [CEO] => Morty  [occ] => 0) 
)
```

Then **sort them by occ** so Google will be first, Apple second, Hardsoft third and so on.

How can I archive it?

Comment: Have you tried something? (code;research;pseudo code)

Comment: [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

Comment: Are my comments ignored again?

Comment: So where are we with this question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

First of I use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get an array with the `id's` from the first array as "lookup table". Then I use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reindex the second array.

After this I start with looping through the second array and reassigning the id, by simply using the key from the innerArray + 1. So that you don't have duplicate id's.

Then I look with [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) if the new id is in the lookup table  and if yes I assign the value `occ` from the first array to the second array. If not I simply assign 0 as value of the key `occ` in the second array.

After that is all done, it is a simple sort with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to compare the values of `occ` and sort it by it's value (Note: If you want to change the sorting from `DESC` to `ASC` just simply change `<` to `>` in the `usort()` call).

```
<?php

    $ids = array_column($arr1, "id");
    $arr2 = array_values($arr2);

    foreach($arr2 as $k => &$v) {
        $v["id"] = ($k+1);
        if(in_array($v["id"], $ids))
            $arr2[$k]["occ"] = $arr1[array_search($v["id"], $ids)]["occ"];
        else
            $arr2[$k]["occ"] = 0;
    }           

    usort($arr2, function($a, $b){
        if($a["occ"] == $b["occ"])
            return 0;
        return $a["occ"] < $b["occ"] ? 1 : -1;
    });

    print_r($arr2);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [company_name] => Google
            [CEO] => Mike
            [occ] => 14
        )

    //...

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [company_name] => Bmw
            [CEO] => Steve
            [occ] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this explanation its looks so simple for me now, thanks!

Comment: @Michoser You're welcome! I'm happy that the explanation helped you to understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

first change your first array to an associative one where the ids are keys - so the most basic way would just be a simple loop

```
$lookup_array = [];    
foreach ($firstarray as $row) {
   $lookup_array[$row['id']] = $row['occ'];
}
```

then you can just loop through the second array and add what you need

```
foreach ($second_array as &$row) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $occ = isset($lookup_array[$id]) ? $lookup_array[$id] : 0;
  $row['occ'] = $occ;
}
```

notice the & pointer to make $row a reference to the array element.

good luck

Comment: Take a sharp look at OP's expected output and OP's second array. Look at the id's.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via iteration something like this

```
$first_array=Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [occ] => 14 ) 
 [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [occ] => 12 ) 
 [2] => Array ( [id] => 4 [occ] => 2 ) 
);

$second_array=Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [company_name] => Google   [CEO] => Mike ) 
 [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [company_name] => Apple    [CEO] => Jones) 
 [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [company_name] => Bmw      [CEO] => Steve) 
 [3] => Array ( [id] => 3 [company_name] => Hardsoft [CEO] => Lucy ) 
 [4] => Array ( [id] => 4 [company_name] => Lays     [CEO] => Morty) 
)

$third_array=$second_array;

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($second_array);$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($first_array);$j++)
    {
        if($second_array[$i][id]==$first_array[$j][id])
        {
            $third_array[$i][occ]=$first_array[$j][occ];
        }
    }    
    if(!isset($third_array[$i][occ]))  
    {
        $third_array[$i][occ]=0;
    }
}
```

now check it via debugging

```
var_dump($third_array);
```

Probably you will see something like this

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [company_name] => Google   [CEO] => Mike   [occ] => 14) 
 [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [company_name] => Apple    [CEO] => Jones  [occ] => 12) 
 [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [company_name] => Bmw      [CEO] => Steve  [occ] => 0) 
 [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [company_name] => Hardsoft [CEO] => Lucy   [occ] => 2) 
 [4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [company_name] => Lays     [CEO] => Morty  [occ] => 0) 
)
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete one to all solution with sorting as well :)

```
$a = array ( 
 0 => array ( 'id' => 1, 'occ' => 14 ),  
 1 => array ( 'id' => 2, 'occ' => 12 ),  
 2 => array ( 'id' => 4, 'occ' => 2 ),  
);

$b = array ( 
'0' => array ( 'id' => 1, 'company_name' => 'Google',   'CEO' => 'Mike' ),  
'1' => array ( 'id' => 2, 'company_name' => 'Apple',    'CEO' => 'Jones'), 
'2' => array ( 'id' => 2, 'company_name' => 'Bmw',      'CEO' => 'Steve'), 
'3' => array ( 'id' => 3, 'company_name' => 'Hardsoft', 'CEO' => 'Lucy' ),  
'4' => array ( 'id' => 4, 'company_name' => 'Lays',     'CEO' => 'Morty'), 
);


$result = []; 
foreach($b as $b_key => $b_val) {
    $merge_array = getSubArrayOnId($b_val['id'], $a);//get portion to be merged from $a
    if(!empty($merge_array))
        $result[] = $b_val + $merge_array;
    else
        $result[] = $b_val + ['occ' => 0]; 
}

//now sorting using user defined function
usort($result, 'cmpOcc');

function getSubArrayOnId($id, $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
        if($val['id'] == $id) {
            return $array[$key];//return the actual sub-array
        }
    }
    return [];//if nothing found return empty array
}

function cmpOcc($a, $b) {
  return $b['occ'] - $a['occ'];
}
```

Now using print_r we will get the following result.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

**Output (Sorted):**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [company_name] => Google
            [CEO] => Mike
            [occ] => 14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [company_name] => Bmw
            [CEO] => Steve
            [occ] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [company_name] => Apple
            [CEO] => Jones
            [occ] => 12
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [company_name] => Lays
            [CEO] => Morty
            [occ] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [company_name] => Hardsoft
            [CEO] => Lucy
            [occ] => 0
        )

)
```